# How can I use CSS, Javascript, or a Cookie to disable animation reply on back button?

Tags: javascript, css, cookies, css-animations

I tried to find an article on this but I couldn't find one so here I am posting hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have a CSS keyframe animation that plays on the homepage of my website. Is there a way I can have it play when someone comes to the homepage but keep it from replaying over and over again when someone uses the browser's back button to go back to the homepage?

I'd love it if this was a quick CSS or JavaScript fix but if that's not possible is there a way to use a cookie to disable the animation class?

Thanks!!

Comment: Would this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166999/how-can-i-stop-a-css-keyframe-animation

Comment: JS: `document.body.dataset.hit=localStorage.hit||0; localStorage.hit=1; ` CSS: `body[data-hit='0'] .animationClass {}` ; use the body attrib as a namespace on your existing CSS animation-pointing rule, and apply the body attrib after the first load...

Comment: I don't think the first one will work because the iteration count is reset after the page is refreshed. I.E. when the back button is pressed. I'm looking into the second solution proposed by @dandavis though.

Comment: @dandavis I didn't do this right... Any chance you could help me with syntax? I really appreciate it. 
<script>
 document.body.dataset.hit=localStorage.hit||0; localStorage.hit=1;
 </script>
CSS: 

#logo-hp {
    -webkit-animation: animate 3s ease;
    -moz-animation: animate 3s ease;
    -ms-animation: animate 3s ease;
    -o-animation: animate 3s ease;
 [at sign]namespace body[data-hit='0']
}
I don't think I put the namespace in correctly? Could you help me with where to put it?

Comment: `#logo-hp` should be `body[data-hit='0'] #logo-hp` if there are other non-animation styles in there, put them in a "plain" `#logo-hp`  rule like you had before, so they are not toggled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of your homepage (just before `</body>`) add:

```
<script>
function startAnimation() {
var cookie = document.cookie;

if (cookie.indexOf('preventAnimation=true') === -1) {
    document.getElementById('elementToBeAnimated').setAttribute('class','animate');
    }

}

function setPreventAnimationCookie() {
document.cookie = 'preventAnimation=true; path=/';
}

window.onload = startAnimation();
window.onbeforeunload = setPreventAnimationCookie();
</script>
```

The first function checks `document.cookie` to see if it contains the name-value pair `preventAnimation=true`. If it does *not* contain that name-value pair, the script applies `class="animate"` to the element which has the property `id="elementToBeAnimated"`.

The second function establishes a session cookie just before the user exits the homepage, and writes to the cookie the name-value pair `preventAnimation=true` so that any visitor who returns to the homepage (after now leaving it) will no longer see the animation (see the first function).